# Javascript - Problem breaking a cyclic dependency

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure in my app

```
content/
   helpers/
      parsers/
         parseComment.js
         index.js

      index.js

   interactions.js

   index.js
```

In parseComment.js module I am doing:

```
import { isLiked } from "../../interactions";
```

And, at the same time, in interactions.js module I am doing:

```
import parseComment from "./helpers/parsers/parseComment";
```

Which results in the following cycle:

```
interactions.js -> helpers/parsers/parseComment.js -> interactions.js
```

I have tried modifying the interactions module import, like this:

```
import { parseComment } from "./helpers/parsers";
```

or this

```
import { parseComment } from "./helpers";
```

in order to use a third module (index.js)... but, the cycle still exists.

How can I break it?

Note:

1. in content/index.js I am exporting interactions.js
2. in content/helpers/index.js I am exporting the parsers files and other stuff contained in the helpers folder
3. in content/helpers/parsers I am exporting all the parsers

Comment: Just in case you want to use a fancy term, this is also be called a cyclic dependency xD

Comment: Really the thing to do is get rid of the circular dependencies. Create a new module if you have to.

Comment: Adding on top of what @Pointy said, you can also setup dependency injection if you don't mind following OOP patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `isLiked` to a new file:

```
content/
   helpers/
      parsers/
         parseComment.js
         index.js
      likes.js
      index.js

   interactions.js

   index.js
```

Make sure that new file is NOT dependent on interactions.js. That should break your cyclic dependency.

If `isLiked` DOES depend on other things in interactions.js, then I'm afraid you have some surgery ahead of you.

Comment: Done! I just moved it to a scripts folder, as it looks little strange for me having it in a helpers folder as the method is used in multiple files, not as a helper or utility. It works!